# Not understanding solution Probability problem solved using multiplication rule

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Here is an example probability problem from Introduction to Probability 2nd edition (Bertsekas and Tsitsiklis).  It is example 1.11 and i'm having brain barriers getting past even the first part of the solution.

Problem:

A class consisting of 4 grad and 12 undergrad students is randomly divided into 4 groups of 4.  What is the probability that each group includes a grad student?  (Randomly means that  given the assignment of some students to certain slots, any of the remaining students is equally likely to be assigned to any of the remaining slots.)

The grad students are denoted by 1,2,3, and 4.

The solution is broken into parts, the first which is to find the probability that students 1 and 2 are in different groups. So we pick a grad student at random and assign them to one of the four groups.  That leaves 3 grad students and 12 undergrad students (15 remaining students total) that need to be assigned to the remaining 3 groups which we can consider as constituting 12 slots.

Now the book says that Probability(students 1 and 2 are in different groups) is:  12/15, since there are 12 slots in groups other than the one of student 1, and there are 15 student slots overall.

I don't understand how they got to that number (12/15). I am trying to
understand this in terms of size of sample space (15 it seems) and what
the 'event' would be. I guess I
am trying to understand in terms of counting, but failing royally.

Any guidance much appreciated.

**SOME NOTES:  AFTER I REVIEWED THE SELECTED SOLUTION:**

After looking at Metehan's answer (thanks, Metehan!) and thinking about this more
it's making a lot more sense.  If anyone else had trouble like me, maybe it will
help if I describe how I am seeing it now.

For all student->seat assignment outcomes we pick an arbitrary student -- say student 1 --
and we look at all seats and groups other than the
seat/group where student 1 ended up.  Of the 15 remaining seats, 12 of those are associated
with groups distinct from the group where student 1 ended up. These are the 'special' seats
where the remaining grad students must be assigned in order to avoid 'more than one grad student
in a group'.

Now we consider another grad student -- lets call them student 2.
Since student 1 occupied one of the 16 seats there are 15 seats remaining where student 2 could be assigned.
Any one of the fifteen remaining seats has a 1/15 chance of being selected for student 2 to sit in.
Now if we picked two seats at random from the remaining 15,
we have doubled the chances of student 2 being selected for one
of those seats. Continuing by picking 12 'special' seats (all in groups other than the
one selected for student 1), we see we have the probability of student 2 being assigned to one
of those 'special/non-conflicting seats' is: 12/15.

This is how it is now making sense to me ;^)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine there are 16 seats in groups of 4.

```
----|----|----|----|
```

Imagine the first grad student sits in a random place.

```
----|----|--x-|----|
```

No matter where this student actually sits, he will be seated in one of these groups of 4. However, the second grad student must sit in 12 of the remaining 15 seats to avoid being placed in the same group with him.

```
aaaa|aaaa|--x-|aaaa|
```

$a$ means, "available" :)

Edit: I guess the book should continue like this. We found the first probability to be $\frac{12}{15}$. When the second grade student sits at a random place, there are 14 seats left. But 8 of them are the seats we want. Then the probability of a 3rd grad student sitting where we want is $\frac{8}{14}$. Likewise, for 4th grad the possibility will be $\frac{4}{13}$. Now, multiple them all and find the result.